# Excel VBA Array results Offset

Tags: excel, vba

I have developed an array based on the results of input into a worksheet.  Using a command button I am able to populate necessary data into a Delay sheet.  The problem I face is that I can't get the array results to spread out the way that I want on the Delay Sheet.  On the delay sheet, there is a one column offset between 10 & 11 and a 4 column offset between 13 & 14.

```
    arval = "" 'This will be the total strig value of the individual array values that are captured
    a = 0 'counts the total number of rows of data that exist in the array

    For i = 2 To lr  'Start the array
        aval = wsg.Range("A" & i).Value

        If aval = "Y" Then  'Set the search parameters
            arval = wsg.Range("B" & i).Value & "~#pop#~"  'Start collecting data with the B column

                For j = 3 To 14
                    arval = arval & wsg.Cells(i, j).Value & "~#pop#~"   'continue collecting information in the various columns
                Next j
            ReDim Preserve array1(a)
            array1(a) = arval
            a = a + 1
        End If

    Next i

    wsd.Range("G2:X15").ClearContents  'Clears the inserts range

If a > 0 Then
    cr = 2
    For i = LBound(array1) To UBound(array1)
        cc = 7
        newarr = Split(array1(i), "~#pop#~")
        For j = LBound(newarr) To UBound(newarr)
            wsd.Cells(cr, cc).Value = newarr(j)
            cc = cc + 1
        Next j
        cr = cr + 1
    Next i
End If
```

I've been looking at using the offset function but can't figure out how to use it within the code effectively.  I also thought about using an additional array, like using a "b" variable and then setting the cc to 11 and continue to display the information.  I'm all sorts of confused.
I want to skip a column between 10 and 11.  That's the goal.  If I can get one I can get the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Add some conditional maths based on the premise that false is zero and true is minus one.

```
    For j = LBound(newarr) To UBound(newarr)
        wsd.Cells(cr, cc).Value = newarr(j)
        cc = cc + 1 + (abs(cc=10)) + (abs(cc=13)*4)
    Next j
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest setting your target range as non-contiguous, e.g.

```
dim r as range
set r  = wsd.range("G2:P2,R2:T2,X2:X2")
```

Then use offset, like this (I'm assuming that the lbound of your array is 0).  Also you will be able to dispense with the cc / cr counting stuff, since the range should handle that...

```
    For j = LBound(newarr) To UBound(newarr)
        r.offset(i,0) = newarr(j)
    Next j
```

Can't test that here, so you will probably need to correct my code!